# Coded UI test for Windows Phone 8.1 without emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to create my first coded ui test for windows phone 8.1, but I can't install emulator on my pc because of my processor(does not support hyper V). So my question is: Can I create coded ui test and run it on my Windows phone, or i have to install emulator for this kind of test?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN testing directly on device should be supported:

**Q: Can tests be executed on the emulator only, or can I also use a physical device?**
A: Either option is supported. The target for test execution is selected by changing the emulator type or selecting device in the device toolbar. If Device is selected, a Phone Blue device needs to be connected to one of the machine’s USB ports.

However creating tests without the emulator is not possible:

**Q: Do I have to deploy the Windows Phone app in the emulator in order to map UI controls?**
A: Yes, the coded UI test builder requires that an emulator be running and the app be deployed to it. Otherwise, it will throw an error message saying that no running emulator could be found.

see [Test Windows Phone 8.1 Apps with Coded UI Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn747198.aspx) on MSDN